# jQuery Draggable / Resizble with Crop and overflow issue

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, overflow, crop

ok now, I have two issues that are annoying me.  see fiddle first for better understanding.

https://jsfiddle.net/TheDeveloper/y6qgchzL/

**first:**  i got a crop area on my image (overlay),  which allows the user to select a area on the image they like to crop.    Now i dont want to perform a real crop instead i like to hide the rest of the image,  but the resizble still needs to work.  Im not sure exactly if my approach is correct.

**second:**  the main green container got a overflow hidden on it, which is fine. but would it be possible to show the resizble handles out side the overfolow but keep the image hidden?

code used so far:

```
$('#theone').draggable({  containment: "parent"});
$("#theone").resizable({handles: "n, e, s, w"});

    $('#btntheone').click(function() {
        $('#theoneinner').remove();
        $('<div id="theoneinner"></div>').appendTo('#theone');
        $('#theoneinner').draggable({containment: "#theone", });
        $('#theoneinner').resizable({handles: "n, e, s, w"});
    })


    $('#btncrop').click(function() {
        if ($('#theoneinner').length > 0) {
            var $obj = $("#theoneinner");
            var height = $obj.height();
            var width = $obj.width();
            var top = $obj.position().top;
            var left = $obj.position().left;
            alert('Top:' + top + '\nLeft:' + left + '\nHeight:' + height + '\nWidth:' + width);
        } else {
            alert('add overlay');
        }
    });
```